# Linux - Is there a way to convert .bz2 files to .tar.bz2 files using pipes?

Tags: tar, bzip2, bz2

Is there a way to convert a .bz2 file to a .tar.bz2 file without decompressing the entire thing to disk and then re-compressing?  The decompressed size is larger than my drive.  Since bz2 operates on blocks, it would seem like you could just decompress a block, pipe it, re-compress it, remove the decompressed block from memory, etc.

I asked this [on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1273813) and didn't find an answer.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Originally it was to work with very large data files without uncompressing them.  archivemount lets you mount .tar.bz2 (because it has "filesystem" inside), but not .bz2.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=ArchiveFileSystems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** My original answer doesn't work at all, sorry.  `tar` won't accept a data stream from STDIN as input, so the first command fails.

The only way I can think of to accomplish what you want is to write your own program to add the required `tar` headers and such around your data stream.  Then you could write:

```
$ bzcat foo.bz2 | stream-to-tar | bzip - > foo.tar.bz2
```

... and (assuming your program gets the `tar` format right) you could decompress it with a standard `tar xf foo.tar.bz2`.

---

<strike>This probably isn't how you want to do it, since it doesn't provide any of the usual advantages of tar'ing the file in the first place.</strike>

```
$ bzcat foo.bz2 | tar cjf foo.tar.bz2 -
```

Now, the problem is that tar doesn't include any filesystem in it cause all we've given it is a decompressed data stream.  That means you need to decompress/untar it like this:

```
$ tar --to-stdout -xjf foo.tar.bz2 > foo
```

Comment: what version of tar is this?  doesn't work with GNU tar 1.16.1.

Comment: GNU tar 1.20 on debian, 1.21 on cygwin. hmm. you're right, the first command doesn't seem to work. tar sez `tar: -: Cannot stat: No such file or directory`. it doesn't seem to like STDIN. the second command would work, assuming the first one did.

Comment: `tar` doesn't accept a data stream from STDIN, it must be a list of files.

Comment: @sirlancelot: correct, thx.  fixed my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find that the answer is:  You don't do this.  The compression gained from a `.tbz2` file vs. a `.bz2` file is pretty minimal if you compressed it with `--best`.  Here is an example over an httpd error log:

```
 39M ./httpd-error.log
904K ./httpd-error.log.bz2
904K ./httpd-error.log.tbz2
```

Otherwise, you'll have to do it with a stop by the hard drive.

Comment: I wasn't doing it for the compression.  I was doing it because a .tar.bz2 can be mounted without uncompressing it, but a .bz2 can't.  For very large compressed files (OSM maps and Wikipedia dumps are both extremely large XML files stored as .bz2, for instance), you really don't want to decompress the entire thing to your drive in order to use it.

Comment: Then I guess I would need to know what you want to do with this file?  Are you looking to parse with a programming language, search through it, etc?

Comment: Both of those, yes.